# How can I convert a nested list into a numpy array to prevent the ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor in a keras model

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, keras

Hello I am trying to generate synthetic data to use them as input inside a simple model for now.

Here is the code for creating the generic data:

```
trajectories = 200
y = 20 #degrees
ns0 = 180 #contact surface initial value
r = 0.003 # roller radiues
vPoisson = 0.3
youngModulus = 2.1 * 1e11
relevantImpalance = 20 *1e-5 #kg.m
systemMass = 5 #kg
rotationSpeed = 2* np.pi*70 #Hz
steps = 1/400

def hertz_elastic_contact(r = r, v = vPoisson, e = youngModulus):
    return 2/3 * np.sqrt(r) * e/(1-np.square(v))

def total_contact_stiffness(y = y, ns = ns0):
    kp = hertz_elastic_contact()
    a =  np.power(1/kp, 2/3)
    b = np.power(np.cos(y), 5/2)
    c = ns * kp
    disc = a + np.power(b/c, 2/3)
    
    return 1/disc

def healthy_trajectories(trajectories = trajectories):
    healthyTime = []
    for i in range(trajectories):
        healthyTime.append(random.randint(2,20))
    
    return healthyTime

def stiffness_calculation(healthy, steps = steps, ns = ns0, nsStart = ns0):
    Kp = hertz_elastic_contact()
    kts = total_contact_stiffness()
    ktsThreshold = kts / 5
    
    i = 1
    stiffness = []
    time = []
    while kts > ktsThreshold:
        kts = 1/ (( np.power(1/Kp,2/3) + np.power(np.power(np.cos(y),5/2) / (ns * Kp) * steps * i, 2/3) ))
        kts += np.random.normal(kts/10, kts/20, None)

        ns = np.absolute(nsStart - steps * i)
        ns += np.random.normal(ns/10, ns/20, None)
        stiffness.append(kts)
        time.append(healthy + steps * i)
        i += 1
    return stiffness, time

def stiffness_degradation(healthy):
    stiffnessList = []
    daysList = []
    gap = 100
    
    for i in range(len(healthy)):
        monitoringPoint = []
        days = []
        stiffness, time = stiffness_calculation(healthy[i])
        print(i)
        for j in range(int(len(stiffness)/gap)):
            monitoringPoint.append(stiffness[j*gap])
            days.append(time[gap*j])
            
        
        monitoringPoint.append(stiffness[-1])
        days.append(time[-1])
        stiffnessList.append(monitoringPoint)
        daysList.append(days)
    return stiffnessList, daysList

def total_stiffness(healthy, stiffness, degradationDays):
    stiffnessTotal = []
    DaysTotal = []
    healthyPointMonitoring = []
    for i in range(len(stiffness)):
        healthyStiffness  = stiffness[i][0]
        stiffnessHealthy = int(healthy[i] * 4) * [healthyStiffness]
        healthyPointMonitoring.append(len(stiffnessHealthy))
        days = [healthy[i] / 4]  * len(stiffnessHealthy)
        
        stiffnessHealthy.extend(stiffness[i])
        days.extend(degradationDays[i])
        stiffnessTotal.append(stiffnessHealthy)
        DaysTotal.append(days)
    
    return stiffnessTotal, DaysTotal, healthyPointMonitoring

healthyList = healthy_trajectories()
a,b = stiffness_degradation(healthyList)
finalStiff, finalDays, healthyMonitoring = total_stiffness(healthyList, a,b)

RUL = []
for i in range(len(finalDays)):
    rulTemp = [np.max(finalDays[i]) - x for x in finalDays[i]]
    RUL.append(rulTemp)
```

Let's say I want to train this following model by using finalStiff as X and RUL as y:

```
modelTest = keras.Sequential ([
   
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    
    layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    
    layers.Dense(1)
])


modelTest.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mae', metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()])
```

For this I did a `finalStiffNp = np.array(finalStiff, dtype = object)` and `rulArray = np.array(rulList, dtype=object)`. WHen i am trying to fit the model like this : `history=modelTest.fit(finalStiffNp , rulTestArray)`, I ran into this error:
**ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).**

How can I fix this error. Thanks

Comment: why did you specify `dtype=object`?  Keras is trying to use `dtype=float`

Comment: try to show the full error message